# persist firebase data in react-native app

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to build my first app on react-native, but I have problem with that. I want to show my data from firebase and also the data which insert to firebase does not get deleted when I reload the app. That's what I have in my render:

```
 let tags = this.state.tagArray.map((val, key) => {
  return <TagContainer key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
    deleteMethod={() => this.deleteTag(key)} />
});
```

this is my firebase config:

```
this.itemRef=this.getRef().child('tags');
getRef(){
  return firebaseApp.database().ref();
}

getItems(itemRef){
  itemRef.on('value',(snap)=>{
    let items=[];
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      items.push({
        title:child.val().title,
        _key:child.key
      });   
    });
 Array.prototype.push.apply(this.state.tagArray, items);
  this.setState({ tagArray: this.state.tagArray })
  });
```

this my addtag function where I set my tagArray:

```
addTag() {
  if (this.state.tagText) {
    this.state.tagArray.push({
      'tag': this.state.tagText
    });
    this.setState({ tagArray: this.state.tagArray })
    this.setState({ tagText: '' })
    this.itemRef.push({title:this.state.tagText});
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you set `this.state.tagArray`?

Comment: addTag() {
    if (this.state.tagText) {
      this.state.tagArray.push({
        'tag': this.state.tagText
      });
      this.setState({ tagArray: this.state.tagArray })
      this.setState({ tagText: '' })
      this.itemRef.push({title:this.state.tagText});
     
    }
  }

Comment: Please edit your question and add the related code there.

Comment: sure, I edited my question.

Comment: When do you run this `addTag` function?

Comment: when I press the button

Comment: I change my getItems function, please check again.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to push data into state object. No state changes are allowed without using setState().

```
addTag() {
  if (this.state.tagText) {

      let tagArray = [...this.state.tagArray,{'tag': this.state.tagText}]
      this.setState({ tagArray: tagArray,tagText: '' }, ()=>{
          this.itemRef.push({title:this.state.tagText});
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I change my getItems function, please check again.
Thank you